# MODX package management not showing up

Tags: modx

I just installed MODX on my server to start building my site. I have used MODX on a couple of different occasions, but this time after the install when I click on package management to install wayfinder and others I don't see anything at all, it's just blank. Here is the error I get in the reports:

[2013-09-23 11:16:55] (ERROR @ /connectors/layout/modx.config.js.php) Error caching action map mgr/actions

what does this mean exactly? I deleted everything the first time and completely reinstalled it to no avail. Has this ever happened to anyone else before? Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Things not showing up in the manager is usually your compress js and compress css settings in the modx system settings....

- clear the modx cache
- clear your browser cache & cookies
- switch both compression settings to off

Give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

Go to system settings and find compress_css and compress_js. Turn both settings to no. Clear cache, flush sessions, login and check if this helped